# Make spring loaded folders open in front?

Tags: macos, finder

Is it possible to make spring loaded folders open in front of the active window? Just recently they have been opening behind the window I'm dragging into and that makes navigation difficult.

Ideally I'd just like the folder to expand (in list view) but that doesn't seem to be an option when I'm traversing to different locations (links from the Favourites bar).

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I should have been in column view, not list view. Someone changed it and I thought list was what I was using.